# Why isn't my button centering like other elements?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3.x and I have a div that is position relative and the button (a tag) is set to position absolute because I want the button to be at the bottom: 10px;.

I also want the button centered. Why is it semi centered here? (I used the text-center class).

See jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0dhcoucd/4/

CSS:

```
.box-badge-orange {
  background-color: orange;
  position:relative;
  height:30em;
}

.box-badge-orange a {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.divaround {
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: First of all, you have inconsistent html. Close your p tags, and try to not add a div in a p tag. And you have set your button to position absolute.

Comment: Thanks for catching the typo, but that doesn't resolve the issue, nor does it have any effect on the output in this case.

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46534250/5236174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with this kind of problem, add borders to the involved element, that will provide you the information of their position and you will get the idea what is wrong.

Instead of having "button/link" absolute and bottom, make the wrapper(check div with class `.place-bottom`) absolute, and with width:100% and use `.text-center` to have button/link center inside the wrapper div.

```css
.box-badge-orange {
  background-color: orange;
  position:relative;
  height:30em;
}

.box-badge-orange .place-bottom {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  width:100%
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">



<div class="box-badge-orange">
      <h2>Title Here</h2>
      <p class="text-center">Lorem ipsum</p>
      <div class="place-bottom text-center">
          <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" 
             href="/providers/physician-network/about/Pages/Leadership.aspx">
               Click here
          </a>
    </div>
</div>
```